# how to repeat my code a specific amount of times java?

Tags: java, loops, do-while

import java.util.*;

public class guessingGame

{

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    public static void main(String[] args)

{
      int random, up=0, down=0, x=3, guess=0, nop;


      System.out.println(" Please enter an upper bound number! ");

      up = console.nextInt();

      System.out.println(" Please enter a lower bound number! ");

      down = console.nextInt();



      nop = (up - down) - 1 ;

      random = (int)(Math.random() * (nop)) + (down);




      do {

        System.out.println(" Please guess a number between " + up + " and " + down);

      guess = console.nextInt();

      if(guess == random)

        System.out.println("You guessed the right number! CONGRATULATIONS!");

       else if(guess < random)

        System.out.println("Sorry you should guess higher! Try again!");

      else if(guess > random)

        System.out.println("Sorry you should guess lower! Try again!");

      x--;

      }

      while( x>0);


    }
```

}

> run guessingGame
>    Please enter an upper bound number! 
>    [DrJava Input Box]
>    Please enter a lower bound number! 
>    [DrJava Input Box]
>    Please guess a number between 3 and 1
>    [DrJava Input Box]
>   Sorry you should guess lower! Try again!
>    Please guess a number between 3 and 1
>    [DrJava Input Box]
>   You guessed the right number! CONGRATULATIONS!
>    Please guess a number between 3 and 1
>    [DrJava Input Box]
>   Sorry you should guess lower! Try again!

The problem I'm currently having is that my loop still continues even though i get the right answer. I'm also having a brain fart on how to ask the user if they want to replay the game, I'm not positive on how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

you should make x = 0 if the user guessed the right answer in your if statement

```
if(guess == random){

        System.out.println("You guessed the right number! CONGRATULATIONS!");
x = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add a *flag* to remember if you found a match:

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
  int random, up=0, down=0, x=3, guess=0, nop, found = 0;


  System.out.println(" Please enter an upper bound number! ");

  up = console.nextInt();

  System.out.println(" Please enter a lower bound number! ");

  down = console.nextInt();



  nop = (up - down) - 1 ;

  random = (int)(Math.random() * (nop)) + (down);




  do {

    System.out.println(" Please guess a number between " + up + " and " + down);

  guess = console.nextInt();

  if(guess == random){

    System.out.println("You guessed the right number! CONGRATULATIONS!");
    found = 1;
   }

   else if(guess < random) 

    System.out.println("Sorry you should guess higher! Try again!");


  else if(guess > random)

    System.out.println("Sorry you should guess lower! Try again!");

  x--;

  }

  while( x>0 && found == 0);


}
```

Comment: Thank you ! That helped a lot. Also any suggestions how I can ask the user if they want to play again? To repeat the "game".